# Cannot run xcode 4.5 new project even only with one label on ios device 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I have xcode 4.5 installed on my mac running mountain lion. And i have a jailbroken iphone 4 ios 5.1.1

I started a new project on xcode and add one label.

When i try to run it on simulator 6.0 there is no problem, but when i try to run it on my ios device i get this error:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Here is the image

[image]

Comment: That's not an error, look in your console to see what the actual error message is.

Comment: Sorry here is the image http://i.imgur.com/bfmhE.png

Comment: The error is not visible in the image. You can find it in the textbox at the bottom middle, with all the bold text. You should scroll up a bit to see the actual error message

Comment: This one http://i.imgur.com/K3zkx.png ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new project in Xcode 4.5 will have the deployment target set to 6.0, so you wont be able to run it on a 5.1.1 device. Change the deployment target to 5.0

Edit: from your error it looks like you are using an iOS 6 API in 5.x, which will cause a crash. NSLayoutContstraint is iOS 6.0 only. If you havent specifically set this, check that the "Use Autolayout" box is unchecked in all your xibs

Comment: @Hafiz updated my answer. looks like you are trying to use a new API on an old SDK, which you cant do

Comment: Please help me, i'm new with xcode. What should i do? Downgrade the xcode? Thank you

Comment: Basically if you are supporting multiple versions of iOS, you should make sure that any APIs you are using are available. So check with respondsToSelector, or try to create classes with NSClassFromString