# Xcode not transferring app to iPhone (Successfully)

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

I've built a starter app for myself and wanted to transfer it to my iPhone 4 but unfortunately when it's transferred from Xcode to my iPhone, Xcode throws an error which terminates the app (of sorts) and I get nothing on the screen except the app logo. All of which is beyond my understanding.

The debugger shows an error in the main.m file highlighting the following line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

whilst labelling the above line with the following words:
     **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

I would like to point out that my device is jailbroken also. Please let me know what I need to do to get my app running on my device successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fix this depends on which way you're expecting to upload and run your code - i.e. do you upload your code via ssh in a user-specified script, or do you use the apple-provided way with provisioning profiles? Your question is currently lacking the information needed for answering this.

Since you're jailbroken, you should always be able to add a post-build hook which signs the binary using ldid -S, uploads the binary to the iPhone, and runs it.

(You won't be able to use the debugger integrated into XCode without major hackery if you use this way, and there's probably a simpler way of achieving this.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the device recognizes your Apple certificate isn't valid (if you even have one) or the software refuses to run the app on a device that isn't fully legit according to Apple's standards.

That is one reason but that's something I'm fully certain. I searched stackoverflow and found [another possible explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561543/cannot-run-xcode-4-5-new-project-even-only-with-one-label-on-ios-device-5-1-1). This topic states that a new xcode project only runs on the newest OS. At the moment iOS 7 is still in beta so a startup project launches default in iOS 6.1.

To make it run on an older version you'll just need to adjust the deployment target to the version you prefer. Ofcourse working in an older OS will take effect in the language and "set you back". And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770834/can-i-change-my-ios-deployment-target-to-5-0-on-xcode-4-5) is how to change your deployment target. Hope this helped?